# Transfer old e-mails from Outlook OWA account to another

Tags: outlook, outlook-on-the-web

I want to transfer my old e-mails from Office Outlook Web Access to another Microsoft Outlook web App. Soon I will be no longer able to access that account and I have a lot of important e-mails that I need to retain for my reference. Is there any easy way to do that? I know how to redirect the new arriving e-mails to another account but don't know what to do it with old ones.

Comment: You can just export them from the old one and import into the new one. You can just use the desktop version for this. (If you don’t have it installed, just use a trial version of Outlook.)